# Django MongoDB Tastypie error while response

Tags: python, pymongo, tastypie

Dont know what is the issue. The blog I am referring have same steps, cross checked many times.

I have models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

Now I did `syncdb` and I got my `MongoDB` setup.

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from models import Article, Tag

class ArticleResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        Tag.objects.create(
        tag_name='Python'
        )
        queryset = Tag.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'articles'
```

Above class adds data to my MongoDB, but while displaying response it gives error which is really not understandable:

`{"error_message": "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '53ffae131c20d8048c03cd63'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/home/django/env/bheeku/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 201, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/django/env/bheeku/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 432, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/django/env/bheeku/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 464, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/django/env/bheeku/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1299, in get_list\n    bundles.append(self.full_dehydrate(bundle, for_list=True))\n\n  File \"/home/django/env/bheeku/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 854, in full_dehydrate\n    bundle.data[field_name] = field_object.dehydrate(bundle, for_list=for_list)\n\n  File \"/home/django/env/bheeku/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 135, in dehydrate\n    return self.convert(current_object)\n\n  File \"/home/django/env/bheeku/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 234, in convert\n    return int(value)\n\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '53ffae131c20d8048c03cd63'\n"}`

What exactly is wrong?

However it is returning

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 0}, "objects": []}
```

when there is no data in table.

Comment: The error message suggests you are passing an value that is trying to be cast to an `int()` but is invalid. The value is the string `53ffae131c20d8048c03cd63` which looks like a MongoDB ObjectId. It's hard to know what's going wrong without seeing the code you're calling (or a reference to the blog post), but hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm but unable to understand how to fix it. The above is it which I have as working.

Comment: Django is auto-adding an "id" field to your Tag model (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields). In tastypie/fields.py at line 234, they try to cast the MongoDB id to an integer.

Comment: @xbello yes but howto fix it?